# FastAPI / SQLAlchemy Create Multiple Users

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

I work a working API endpoint to create a single user.

```py
@app.post("/entity/", response_model=List[schemas.User])
def create_user(user: schemas.User, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    crud.create_user(db=db, user=user)
    return JSONResponse(content={"message": "user created successfully"})

class User(BaseModel):
    id: str = Field(default_factory=generate_id)
    first_name: Optional[str] = ""
    last_name: Optional[str] = ""
    username: str

class Config:
    orm_mode = True

def create_user(db: Session,  user: schemas.User):
    db_item = models.User(**user.dict())
    db.add(db_item)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_item)
    return db_item
```

This works, but I want to create multiple Users via one api request.

I guess the `create_user` function has to look somewhat like this:

```py
def create_user(db: Session, data,  user: schemas.User):
    objects = []
    for user in data:
        db_item = models.User(**user.dict())
        objects.append(dbitem)
    db.bulk_save_objects(objects)
    db.commit()
```

I just can´t my head around what is the right way to create this kind of bulkinsert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accept a list of users as the request body.

```py
def create_user(db: Session, users: List[schemas.User]):
    objects = []
    for user in users:
        db_item = models.User(**user.dict())
        objects.append(dbitem)
    db.bulk_save_objects(objects)
    db.commit()
```